# Batch file that moves all movies to a specific folder file needs renamed

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command

So my problem is that i'm using a batch file to move all movies, images, and so on. I'm using it to organize a very big hard drive over 20GB. So everything was working fine till I got to a new hard drive. I'm getting a file error saying the File name is to long. So my idea was to check if the file name exceeded 250 characters and if it did then to rename the file to only 200 with leaving the file extension alone. I've attached the current code i'm using to make this possible. My Question is how to make this possible. I'm thinking of adding an if command right before the if not exist but am stumped on how to check for the characters in the file name? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
 

@echo off

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set TESTFOLDER=L:\AllMovies
md "%TESTFOLDER%"

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /s /ah /b /a-d L:\*.mov or L:\*.mp4') do (
  call :copyfile "%%~i"
) 

goto :eof

:copyfile
set fname=%~nx1
set counter=0

if not exist "%TESTFOLDER%\%dest%\!fname!" goto docopy

:recheck
if exist "%TESTFOLDER%\%~n1_!counter!%~x1" (
  set /a counter+=1
  goto recheck
)
set fname=%~n1_copy!counter!%~x1

:docopy
copy "%~1" "%TESTFOLDER%\%dest%\!fname!"

goto :eof

endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always prepend `\\?\` to a filename to ignore filename checks. Windows supports filenames up to 32K. However programs tend to only support 260 total characters for the path (of which 255 max for the name).

Write your name to a file then read the file size, it will be the filename size.

Comment: Where would I go about adding this in at? I've tried that already in front of the fname and a few other places and still cannot seem to get it to work. I know its probably something very little but i can't seem to figure it out

Comment: `copy \\?\c:\windows\win.ini \\?\c:\win.ini.old`. NB You have to check your programs can read them.

Comment: I tried to use the above code and it still wouldn't work. Any other suggestions on this?

Comment: `copy "\\?\%~1" "\\?\%TESTFOLDER%\%dest%\%fname%"`

Comment: I tried that as well its still not having it. Here is one of the files that its having a error about. I noticed about 90% of all the errors are all coming from Application Data:

Comment: The directory name L:\mystuff\backup2\All Users\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\Application Data\
Application Data\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\NonCritical_7.6.7600.256_70af5b38b38a10f762485e442cfc35f57eaf3997_cab_07a3f973 is too long.

Comment: Your path isn't right. You are using a compatability path. Did you change file permissions on this folder? If so change them back. Noone has access except for transverse rights (and everyone has them).